# The owner or owner, the shareholders or shareholders

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I just made a sentence like the following :

> One of the basic principles of Capitalism : Some people (**the workers**)
>   must produce more than what they get so some other people (**the owner**
>   and **the shareholders**) can get more than what they produce.

Are the bolded words correct? Since I refer to completely random people

Comment: Used in parentheses as they are, they do not need to form part of any syntax but are only references. Whilst there is no harm in including the articles, they are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2):

The **bold** words are correct, IMO.

But I would not say they refer to completely random individuals.  They each belong to a group or class, certainly according to long established theories in the field.